# Return members of a hashmap through a class get method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, class-members

The following returns the `default` `"client?"`:

```
class ClientMap
    def initialize
        @@clients = {"DP000459": "BP"}
        @@clients.default = "client?"
    end

    def get(id)
        return @@clients[:id]
    end
end

clientMap = ClientMap.new
cKey = "DP000459"
puts clientMap.get(cKey)
```

Could anybody explain why I cannot retrieve anything but the 'default'?

Comment: I strongly suggest you follow some sort of "intro to ruby" tutorial. I appreciate you know how to write code in other languages, but this code **looks** like it's written in another language!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've got two problems. First, you are using the symbol syntax in your hash, which works only if your keys are symbols. If you want keys to be strings, you need to use hash-rocket syntax: `@@clients = {'DP000459' => 'BP'}`.

Second, your method returns `clients[:id]` regardless of what parameter is provided. The key is the symbol `:id` rather than the local variable `id`. You need to change this to `@@clients[id]`.

Here's a cleaned-up version of what you want:

```
class ClientMap

  def initialize
    @@clients = {'DP000459' => 'BP'}
    @@clients.default = 'client?'
  end

  def get(id)
    @@clients[id]
  end
end
```

I've also taken the liberty of making the spacing more Ruby-idiomatic.

Finally, for variable names in Ruby, [use snake_case](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#snake-case-symbols-methods-vars):

```
>> client_map = ClientMap.new
>> c_key = 'DP000459'
>> client_map.get(c_key)
#> "BP"
```

Comment: Aha - of course the : was making id the key rather than using the parameter id, thanks - also for the conventions pointers.

Comment: I have things working now, cheers. Not sure how to 'accept as correct'.

Comment: Perhaps better to use the inbuilt `fetch` method here rather than persisting with `get`?

Comment: Hi - It is as I was thinking in other language idioms. My train of thought would be that the client list should remain private and accessed through a getter. NB : The class once completed will be linked as a 'require_relative' from my main working class - It will just provide a hard-coded lookup - stored in the hash.

Answer (score 0):

Look at these code:

```
h = { foo: 'bar' }               # => {:foo=>"bar"}
h.default = 'some default value' # => "some default value"
h[:foo]                          # => "bar"
h[:non_existing_key]             # => "some default value"
```

You can read [here](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Hash.html#method-i-default) about Hash#default method

> Returns the default value, the value that would be returned by hsh if
>   key did not exist in hsh

Comment: @SergioTulentsev sure

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I will review. I realise the code looked like it was Ruby words superimposed over another language haha

Comment: The OP is using Hash#default properly. Other problems were causing the code not to work.